# Heroku and subdomains

Tags: heroku, dns, cname, amazon-route53

I have the domain `ingledow.co.uk`.  I have recently been working on a Heroku app that is deployed to `david.ingledow.uk`  and this has been done successfully.

However, I now want to redirect all my old domain and subdomains to `david.ingledow.co.uk`.  Here is a list of domains I have that I want to redirect to my new subdomain:

`ingledow.co.uk` > `david.ingledow.co.uk`

`www.ingledow.co.uk` > `david.ingledow.co.uk`

`blog.ingledow.co.uk` > `david.ingledow.co.uk`

I've set CNAMEs to `david.ingledow.co.uk.` but I get the following error:

```
Heroku | No such app
There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting them as CNAME's then they are not redirects - it would be making your site available on www.ingledow.co.uk, blog.ingledow.co.uk. You'd have to add these all as custom domains to your application and then handle the redirect in your app. Instead you could set them up as redirects so when you go to blog.ingledow.co.uk you get redirected to david.ingledow.co.uk at DNS level.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53#naked-root-domain for more info.

Comment: I used DNSimple to forward the domains, but your suggestion sounds a lot better – and cheaper!